# From a string array, create a table

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

Basically, when given a list of strings,

I want to create a table with `select` statement.

For example,

```
"A", "B", "C",
```

I want to create a table as a sub-select like:

```
sub-select
+---------+
|   "A"   |
+---------+
|   "B"   |
+---------+
|   "C"   |
+---------+
```

How do I do this in redshift and postgres?

Thanks!

Update:

select 'a' as A;

is sort of what I want that returns:

```
     a
+---------+
|   "a"   |
+---------+
```

How do I have multiple rows for this column `a` from the query `select 'a' as A;`

Comment: I only got to `select 'a' as A;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the way to convert a column value to multiple rows is using split_part function and UNION.

Here is an example.

Source Table:

```sql
=> CREATE TABLE t_csv (value varchar(64));
=> INSERT INTO t_csv VALUES ('"A","B","C"');
=> INSERT INTO t_csv VALUES ('"D","E"');
=> INSERT INTO t_csv VALUES ('"F","G","H","I"');
=> SELECT * FROM t_csv;
      value
-----------------
 "D","E"
 "A","B","C"
 "F","G","H","I"
(3 rows)
```

Here is the query to get multiple rows.

```sql
=> WITH a AS (SELECT value FROM t_csv)
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT split_part(a.value,',',1) AS value FROM a
UNION
SELECT split_part(a.value,',',2) AS value FROM a
UNION
SELECT split_part(a.value,',',3) AS value FROM a
UNION
SELECT split_part(a.value,',',4) AS value FROM a
)
WHERE value != '';
value
-------
 "A"
 "B"
 "C"
 "D"
 "E"
 "F"
 "G"
 "H"
 "I"
(9 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have no chance to test it in db, but something like that

```
select * INTO table from (
SELECT CAST('A' AS VARCHAR(100)) AS col
UNION ALL
SELECT 'B' AS col
UNION ALL
SELECT 'C' AS col
) a
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `string_to_array` and `unnest`

```
select *
from unnest(string_to_array('"A","B","C"', ','))
```

(But I don't know if that is available in Redshift)

Comment: I get `function unnest(text[]) does not exist
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You may need to add explicit type casts.
`

Comment: The Redshift apparently does not have this function (Postgres does)